# Extend ${\bigl(1+\frac1x\bigr)}^{{x}}$ to $\overline{\mathbb R}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, extension-field, infinity

We can extend these functions to $\overline{\mathbb R}$ by taking limits says [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Miscellaneous).

\begin{align}
\mathrm e^{-\infty} &= 0 \\
\mathrm e^{+\infty} &= \infty \\
\ln{\left|0\right|} &= -\infty \\
\ln{\left|\pm\infty\right|} = +\infty
\end{align}

Then I am going to extend ${\bigl(1+\frac1x\bigr)}^{{x}}$ to $\overline{{\mathbb R}}$,
if according to the Arithmetic operations defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations), I should get $\frac{{1}}{\infty}={0}$, then I think I should extend the function to ${\left({1}+\frac{{1}}{\infty}\right)}^{\infty}={\left({1}+0\right)}^{\infty}={1‌​}$, but according to the limit , I think I should get ${\left({1}+\frac{{1}}{\infty}\right)}^{\infty}={\mathrm e}$
,so what's wrong here ? Which cases the difference ? Which is right ?

Comment: This $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form, since the $1$ is not a constant $1$, it is a variable approaching $1$, so you cannot say $1^{\infty}$ is $1$.

Comment: If you want to extend function properly adding $\pm\infty$ doesn't solve all problems, for example this question. You can extend $\mathbb{R}$ to the hyper-real field $\mathbb{R}^*$, and them use the Transfer principle to extend your function. If you're interested http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis

Comment: @KittyL since $\frac{{1}}{\infty}={0}$ ,thus I get ${\left({1}+\frac{{1}}{\infty}\right)}^{\infty}={\left({1}+0\right)}^{\infty}={1}$, there is no  indeterminate form here.

Comment: @iMath I can't read that last thing; it's not rendering. But $1^\infty$ _is_ indeterminate; you can't give $1^\infty$ a definite answer in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ the same way you can't give one to $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$ or $\infty-\infty$ (the latter two mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations) in the article).

Comment: It is indeterminate. As I mentioned, it is a variable approaching $1$, since your $0$ also comes from $1/\infty$. It essentially depends on whether the $\infty$ in the exponent approaches $\infty$ faster or the $\infty$ in the denominator approaches $\infty$ faster such that the whole expression goes to $\infty$ or $1$ or something in between.

Answer (score 0):

Like KittyL said in the comments, it's wrong to say that it equals $1^\infty$. It depends on what $x$ you look at first.
If you take a look at the inner x first you indeed get that $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ so that $1+\frac{1}{\infty}=1$ and $1^\infty=1$. But if you take a look at the $x$ in the exponent first, you see that $1+\frac{1}{x} > 1, \forall x>0$ so $(1+\frac{1}{x})^\infty = \infty$ no matter what $x$ you fill in.

Both solutions are clearly wrong. You have to look at both $x$'s at the same time. This will give you $e$ as the result.